# Connect Geth to solo network

Tags: go-ethereum, testnets, network

I've done a lot of searching and found lots of information on how to **create** an Ethereum private testnet and etc, as well as **connecting** to the newly created Ethereum private testnet through geth in the terminal and etc, but this is not my question.

My mist app (OSX) already has/had a "solo network" option when I downloaded it, as well as the Main Network, Robsten, and Rinkeby, [as you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2SqP.png). You will also see that I am currently connected to the solo network in Mist.

I do not know, nor can find any information on how to find the chaindata and private keys and etc for the solo network, because when I navigate to the location where the other private keys and etc are located for the other networks (`/Users/username/Library/Ethereum/`), the solo network is not there. ([see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFBlD.png)). So my question is, where is it located?? I can't seem to find it but I know its there because I have and am using it on Mist.

The reason I want to find the location is to connect to it with geth in terminal, and experiment with geth in the terminal and etc.

There might be an obvious answer I've somehow missed, please share!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If im getting you right, you want to connect to the Solo Network created within Mist? I am actually not sure where you can find network files...

But you can try using --dev option when running geth, which should connect to your solo network.

Comment: seems to be located here: `/var/folders/xm/c0_qbn4s5lnfh4n7rs9g32m80000gn/T/geth.ipc`, where is it located on your computer?

Comment: im not using OSX, for me its under "AppData/Local/Temp/ethereum_dev_mode/"